# Getting "Uncaught Exception BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis'" errors when jmeter runs in NON-GUI mode

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am able to run the jmeter in GUI mode by using command like "`jmeter -t my-test.jmx`". However, when I add the "**-n**" (NON-GUI mode) using "`jmeter -n -t my-test.jmx`", I am getting the following error. I am running it on Mac Big Sur, updated to most recent jmeter 5.4.3 (was 5.4.1, both releases have the same error). Also, my java version is "*AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.10+9)*". What could have been the problem?

```
Created the tree successfully using my-test.jmx
Starting standalone test @ Thu Jan 13 16:19:42 EST 2022 (1642108782890)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
Uncaught Exception BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'Script1.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 61 in thread Thread[echoDom (jaxp-serializer) Thread Group 1-1,5,main]. See log file for details.
Uncaught Exception BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'Script2.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 61 in thread Thread[echoDom (jaxp-serializer) Thread Group 1-3,5,main]. See log file for details.
Uncaught Exception BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'Script3.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 61 in thread Thread[echoDom (jaxp-serializer) Thread Group 1-2,5,main]. See log file for details.
...
summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Tidying up ...    @ Thu Jan 13 16:20:34 EST 2022 (1642108834650)
... end of run
```

Comment: Here is my $JAVA_HOME:   
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just stumbled upon the solution. I changed the file "/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.4.3/bin/jmeter". It used to have "JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/opt/openjdk"" inside, which is pointing to a java 17 installation. I replaced the JAVA_HOME with a java 11 location "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home". Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [General Layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout) table of the [Java class file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) wikipedia article

> Java SE 17 = 61 (0x3D hex),

so I think your `AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.10+9)` is wrong, take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), it reports which Java version JMeter is using and my expectation is that you will see Java 17 there.

So you need to point JMeter to use earlier Java version, [JMeter 5.4+](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter5-4-new-features-and-abilities/) is designed to work with [JDK 8](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. You are correct that it appears the jmeter is using "java.version=17.0.1" in the log. However, when I switched default java to "1.8.0_282", jmeter.log is still showing the 17.0.1 being used. I did uninstall and reinstall jmeter (made sure my default jdk is 11 or 8 before I did that). Somehow the 17.0.1 is still used by jmeter. Anyway to change it to use my default $JAVA_HOME? Another puzzling thing is the error only happened in non-gui mode - GUI started up fine although it's also under java 17.0.1 in the log.

Comment: Btw, I don't even have java 17 installed locally. Did jmeter install itself then use it regardless which my local java setting is?

Comment: You do, the question is where. I don't know what your "local java setting" is, JMeter picks up whatever it finds first in the [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). So if you do something like `PATH=/path/to/your/java8/bin:$PATH && export PATH` and then launch JMeter from the same terminal window - it will use Java 8. More information: [Get Started With JMeter: Installation & Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans). You may also find [SDKMAN project](https://sdkman.io/) useful

Comment: Thanks. As you can see, I managed to get it to work. It had something to do with a jmeter launch script somehow was changed so JAVA_HOME pointed to a java 17 installation that I wasn't aware existing.